# Density of states in a 1D infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, density-of-states

The question I have is how would I go about finding the density of states $\frac{dn}{dE}$ of an electron in a 1D infinite potential well with a width of $a$?

I'm only just starting my quantum physics course and only know the basics so I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: But in this case $n(E)$ isn't continuous

Comment: @BioPhysicist To be fair, $n(E)$ is *never* continuous on a finite lattice, yet we talk about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formal form of writing:
$$
  \rho(E) = \sum_n \delta(E - E_n).
$$

where
$$
  E_n = \frac{n^2\hbar^2\pi^2}{2 m a^2}.
$$